# Freeze top row and multiple columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet in which I want to keep all of columns A:H *and* all of row 1 always visible while I scroll through data in the other section.  I've tried using Freeze Panes and some other settings, but just can't seem to get it quite right.

Is there something I've missed, or is this something that can't be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To lock both rows and columns, click the cell below and to the right of the rows and columns that you want to keep visible when you scroll [(source)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-HP010342542.aspx).

Select `I2`. Now go to the `View` ribbon and click `Freeze Panes`. Choose the first option which will freeze the columns and rows to the left and above your selection.

[image: Freeze Panes option highlighted]

This should work for both Microsoft Excel 2007 and 2010

Comment: That froze A:I and rows 1:12.

Comment: Is this a pivot table or is there already some filtering of some sort? I noticed that on mine but thought it was because I had a bunch of filters on the data.

Comment: No tables, no filters.  There's some named ranges, but none for which this makes sense.

Comment: Weird. I just moved my data to a fresh sheet and have the same problem. I have done this before, but not with so many columns. Wonder if it's a glitch. Will keep looking.

Comment: Ok.  I think I found the answer to the question I asked, but then realized the question I asked is the wrong question.  Select I2, then use Freeze Panes.  This will freeze what I've described, but not quite in the way I really want it.

Comment: Just found it too. Updated the answer.

Comment: See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/492364/freeze-top-row-plus-a-range-in-excel) for my real issue.

Answer (score 1):

To freeze any row, and any column *together*:

1. Unfreeze panes - use the 'View' tab; 'Freeze Panes' option to unfreeze all panes
2. Select the entire row *below* the row to be frozen
3. Select the first *cell* to the *right* of the column to be frozen
4. Freeze panes - use the 'View' tab; 'Freeze Panes'

Comment: I don't think step 2 is needed (and without that, this is the same as the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

Even when the very quick way from [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/492351/freeze-top-row-and-multiple-columns-in-excel/492357#492357) somehow does not work for you, then still no trickery is needed at all:

- Drag the small handles to the left and top of the scrollbars, to split the view:

  [image: handles]
- Or, in the View toolbar, click Split:

  [image: split]

  ...and drag the standard split to adjust it:

  [image: adjusted]
- In the View toolbar, click Freeze panes:

  [image: frozen]

Screenshots are Office 365, but same applies to previous versions.

But: [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/492351/freeze-top-row-and-multiple-columns-in-excel/492357#492357) is much easier!

Answer (score 0):

to freeze multi-columns, you need first to freeze the leading columns in your spreadsheet. then just cut-paste other columns to be the leading column of your spreadsheet. then you will get multi-columns frozen. this work with me in Excel 2010

Comment: But why does the accepted answer not work for you? So much easier: click, freeze.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to keep all of columns A:H and all of row 1 always visible:
Select cell I2 and then click on 'Freeze Panes' option

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer.