# Freeze top row, plus a range, in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible to freeze a range in Excel, and at the same time freeze the top row?  I've gotten the idea of how to freeze rows and columns at the same time, but this doesn't quite accomplish *exactly* what I want to do.

Here's the situation:

I have a spreadsheet with information spanning A1:AB99.  I want to keep all cells in A1:E20, and all of row 1, always visible while I scroll left/right/up/down through the other data.

If I use Freeze Panes at I2, it will freeze the top row and A:H.  However, data in A:H below row 1 will still scroll vertically - this is undesired.

Is there a way to get Excel to do what I'm wanting it to do here?

Comment: Have you tried using the Split Pane feature?

Comment: @CharlieRB Split pane view still scrolls the lower-left boxes, so ends up with the same problem as freeze panes does.

Comment: just as another idea/attempt - there might be some way to solve this with a userform - if I remember right, there are ways to include your table into it. So maybe you can inclue three seperate parts of it into one dialog. However, I don't think this is what you were aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is no way I can think of that will do this. Freezing stuff is about fixing full rows and/or columns.

The only thing I can think of would involve some pretty horrible programming where you would need to create your own pseudo scrolling.

It would probably be easier to do in a web page rather than Excel. Though that would still need significant JavaScript programming.

Comment: Agreed.  I've tried to do this before and got nowhere.  Using split view gives you some different results, but still fails with how Iszi wants to do it.  I even tried inserting a textbox, but you can't anchor that to the screen position, only by cells (so it still scrolls).

Comment: @techturtle, yep, I thought about using a textbox too and I think you could persuade it to stay put but it doesn't actually help because you would loose the cell layout. If I really had to do it, I'd use a custom web interface - but I'd probably want to give up and live in a monastery before I tried it in earnest!