# Is there a way to add a scroll bar to a few columns only in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, scrollbar

Most columns in my Excel sheet are only filled in till about row 50. However, I have 3 consecutive columns that are filled in till about row 150.

Is there any way I can add a scroll bar to these 3 columns so I can scroll down to the bottom rows while leaving the rest of the sheet put?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use the [freeze panes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-HP010342542.aspx) feature.

It's located in the ribbon: `view - window - freeze panes`. You can freeze them along a row or along a column to keep what's above or left of the frozen data from moving out of view.

Comment: That's not really an ideal option, is there no way of adding a scroll bar to a range of cells?

Comment: or is there a way to have columns a,b,c scroll down only till row 50 and columns d, e, f scroll down till 200?

Comment: [no](http://superuser.com/questions/492351/freeze-top-row-and-multiple-columns-in-excel) there [isn't](http://superuser.com/questions/492364/freeze-top-row-plus-a-range-in-excel) in excel